# why use 2 diodes when shifting from 3.3 to 5v?

Tags: boost, level-shifting, logic-level

for the question "how do I go from 3.3 to 5v" people point to the microchip cheat sheet.

The Diode option has one between the data line and 5V so it pulls it almost to zero, the other one seems to only limit the high end.  Why won't this work?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBnIyw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I see only one diode in your figure

Comment: Assuming the data in is within a 3.3V domain (and your schematic is correct), the diode is always on (because the cathode has a maximum value of 3.3V), yielding no higher than about 4V at the output.If it was going the other way (signal at 5V into 3.3V on the right) this would operate as a translator.

Comment: I've never heard of the microchip cheat sheet! All your circuit does is shift a 0 to 3V3 signal to become a 0.7V to 4V signal.

Comment: Microchip [Compiled Tips 'n Tricks Guide](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/01146B.pdf), page 125.

Comment: Maybe if the OP had actually drawn the complete circuit, it would have made more sense. The microchip document gives a pretty clear explanation of what is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues with this circuit.

- If "data in" is a 3.3v signal, then:

  - In low state, (5v-0.7v diode)/10k = 430uA will be back-fed into the 3.3v device. As long as the device can keep it's output low, this will only waste power.
  - In high state, (5v-0.7v-3.3v)/10k = 100uA at 1.0v above the 3.3v supply will be back-fed into the 3.3v device. This can cause latch-up or even damage the device.
  - In the high input state, D1 is on, Data Out will be 3.3v+0.7v of diode = ~4.0v.
  - In the low input state, D1 is on, Data Out will be ~0v+0.7v = ~0.7v

This is assuming the 3.3v device has perfect sourcing and sinking characteristics. 4.0v and 0.7v *should* register as logical high and low for most 5v devices, but always check the datasheet to be sure. Some may specify a maximum TTL \$V_{IL}\$ value of 0.1*Vdd... so in that case, 0.5v and thus, no "low" would ever be valid.